# Performing an XML search on an attribute that may not exist (E4X)

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, e4x

I want to do something like your standard XML E4X attribute check to return an XMLList of results:

```
myXml.someGroup.someItem.(@someAttribute == myVar)
```

Is there a way to do this when @someAttribute doesn't always exist? It's okay if I skip items without the attribute in my search.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could check for property before access it:

```
myXml.someGroup.someItem.(hasOwnProperty("@someAttribute") && @someAttribute == myVar)
```